# Mod "not an answer" flag queue: Display if there's an accepted/high-voted answer

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, not-an-answer, link-only-answers

Lots of "not an answer" flags are for link-only answers. Most of them are of low score and not accepted.

It would be pretty useful if there was a quick way to see if the same question has an accepted or high-score answer - in most of these cases the link-only answer can be deleted (or converted to a comment) without losing good information or deleting the only answer to an old question that - while being a bad answer because of it being link-only - actually answers the question.

In this case it might also be a good idea to enable "convert to comment" even if there are comments (maybe if there are just one or two comments that are not highly upvoted - usually there's just one "this is not a good answer yadda yadda" comment by the same user who flagged the answer anyway).

Comment: Just to clarify for non-mods, this is asking for a quick way to see *from the moderator dashboard* if the answer is accepted or is the only answer to the question.  Currently we have to click through and wait for a page load to see this information.